# Backand - How can I console.log() things from inside Security Actions?

Tags: javascript, sdk, backand

In Backand, underneath `Security & Auth > Security Actions`,
is there any way I can use console.log() to log something when those functions get run on the server side?

I know the Read.me says you can use: 'console.log(object) and console.error(object)', but where do I go to look up the output? So far, I haven't been able to find it in any of the logs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Because Security Actions running as part of signup or sign in action the way to debug them with console.log() is by switching the app to debug mode and then check the console log menu.

To switch the app to debug mode open the Settings --> General and change Debug Mode to True.
To view the console entries open Log --> Console menu.

[image]